# xpath query conditional test comparing 2 numeric values

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xpath-2.0, xpathquery

can someone explain to me why this condition return false in this following xpath query

xml

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <a>ha</a>
> ```

xpath query

count(//a) return 1.

but

test="(count(//a) > 0)" return false?

Thank you

Comment: "*test="(count(//a) > 0)" return false*" How did you arrive at this conclusion?

Comment: You are right. I think putting test="whatever" into xpath query editor will always return false

Comment: `test="whatever"` is not an XPath expression; it's an attribute of an XSLT instruction, e.g. `<xsl:if test="count(//a) > 0">Yes</xsl:if>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the query

```
test="(count(//a) > 0)"
```

`test` refers to a child element of the document node called "test". If there is no such element (which is the case here), then you are comparing an empty set to the string "count(//a) > 0". Comparing an empty set to anything returns false.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you don't need the "" marks.

From the free tool XPathBuilder:

[image]

http://www.bubasoft.net/product/xpath-builder/